# How can I solve Server Error in '/' Application Index has not been initialized?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, sitecore8, azureportal

If I access my home page, show error like this :

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Index has not been initialized.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Index has not been initialized.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

[image]

The error above occurs when I restart Porta Azure like this :

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Before I restarted the azure portal, there was no error

Answer (score 0):

1.Check the Index View with its Controller.

2.Maybe your Object reference is not to an instance of an Object.

3.Check the Controller.

This Error generate from the controller.